# App main window, how is it and the main use of this?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an application that has the start up window for the login, if the login is correct, it open the main window of the application.

When the login is correct, I open the new window in this way (I am using MVVM pattern):

```
PrincipalViewModel miPrincipalViewModel = new PrincipalViewModel();
PrincipalView miPrincipalView = new PrincipalView();
miPrincipalView.DataContext = miPrincipalViewModel;

App.Current.MainWindow.DataContext = null;
App.Current.MainWindow.Close();

miPrincipalView.Show();
```

In this case I don't set the new main window. Another option is this code:

```
PrincipalViewModel miPrincipalViewModel = new PrincipalViewModel();
PrincipalView miPrincipalView = new PrincipalView();
miPrincipalView.DataContext = miPrincipalViewModel;

App.Current.MainWindow.DataContext = null;
App.Current.MainWindow.Close();

App.Current.MainWindow = miPrincipalView;
miPrincipalView.Show();
```

In this second case, I set the main window property to the main window of the application, because the login window is closed.

But I don't see any difference in the behavior in both cases, so I am wondering what is really MainWindow and the use and meaning that is has.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the application being closed in the first case ?

Comment: Yes, in both cases, if I click the "X" button, the application is closed. I can see in the task manager that the application is not running after clicking the "X" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you no longer have an actual MainWindow but that shouldn't be an issue unless you rely on the `Application.Current.MainWindow` property to return a valid reference to a window somewhere in your application or if you have set the [Application.ShutdownMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `OnMainWindowClose`.

The default value is `OnLastWindowClose` which means that your application will shut down as expected when you close the new window anyway.

As the documentation on MSDN says *"the lifetime of some applications may not be dependent on when the main window or last window is closed, or may not be dependent on windows at all.".*

Answer (score 0):

Here is part about what is App.Current.MainWindow from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow(v=vs.110).aspx)

> MainWindow is automatically set with a reference to the first Window
>   object to be instantiated in the AppDomain. You can specify a
>   different main window by setting MainWindow assigning another Windows
>   object to the MainWindow property. If the ShutdownMode property of the
>   Application object is set to OnMainWindowClose, closing the main
>   window causes the application to shut down. It is possible to set the
>   MainWindow property from XAML, if an application's main window is not
>   the window that is produced by setting the StartupUri property in
>   XAML. The two limitations of the XAML approach are: You can specify
>   either a XAML-only Window or a XAML-only NavigationWindow as the main
>   window. You must set the Visibility property of the window you
>   specify, otherwise it won't be shown. The reference to the first
>   Window object to be instantiated is also added as the first item to
>   the Windows collection. If MainWindow is subsequently set with a
>   reference to a different Window, the position of the item with the
>   reference to the main window will change, while the order of items in
>   Windows remains the same. Consequently, always use MainWindow to refer
>   to the main window instead of the first item in Windows.

I think that you just need to set `App.Current.ShutdownMode` to `ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown` before `App.Current.MainWindow.Close();` and call `App.Current.Shutdown` when you will want to close the application.

[MSDN Application.ShutdownMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode(v=vs.110).aspx)